# One to Many And Many To One Insert in Ef 6.0

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern

A doctor have one degree and one degree have many doctors,
[image]
 well when i try to add new doctor ef 6.0 (DbContext) insert the selected degree as new record in Degress Table
i don know why ?

Insert Method :

```
public bool Insert<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        bool result = false;
        try
        {
            Context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
            result  = Context.SaveChanges() > 0;
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            result = false;
            fnLogExceptions(exp);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The insert Section :

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dr = new DB.Doctors();
        ...
        dr.Degrees = dropDownList_Degree.SelectedItem as DB.Degrees;
        ...
        using (var ctx = new Context())
        {
             opState = ctx.Insert<DB.Doctors>(dr);
        }
        ...
    }
```

the new doctor is inserted successfully but also it insert new copy of selected degree

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Degree that you were trying to assign isn't from the database, its from the dropodown list. So the EF thinks its new, therefore inserting a new Degree.

You need to retrieve the existing degree from the database.

```
var dr = new DB.Doctors();

int selectedDegreeID = (int)dropDownList_Degree.SelectedItem.Value;

using (var ctx = new Context())
{
    dr.Degree = ctx.Degrees.Find(selectedDegreeID); // Retrieval and assignment.

    opState = ctx.Insert<DB.Doctors>(dr);
}
```

Comment: 'ctx.Degrees.Find(selectedDegreeID);' it execute a query to DB its performance have problen this way , why we have to fetch something from database that we already have it in memmory ?

Comment: @patachi - What you have in the memory is not an object from entity framework, but an object from the DropDownList. You may convert the SelectedItem to Degrees, but its not from the database hence why the EF thinks its new.